# How to force cv::Mat to behave as a smart pointer

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11

I'm designing c++/CLI library with many dll's and internal usage of opencv. OpenCV matrices are passed between theese dll and that is origin of my question:

Do you how to force cv::Mat to behave similar to std::unique_ptr, std::shared_ptr and std::weak_ptr?

A far as I know cv::Mat behave similar to std::shared_ptr (with reference counter), but what about other types of smart pointers?

Comment: Maybe, you can use the functions such as Mat::clear()/Mat.copyTo()/cv::swap()  to simulate the other smart pointer operations.

Comment: If `cv::Mat` is a C++ wrapper for `CvMat` (C counterpart) then maybe you could make your own `UniqueMat` wrapper with deleted copy constructor or whatever features you need. I guess it might be a little more work, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*By far* the easiest method would be `std::unique_ptr<cv::Mat>`. It has the additional benefit of being obvious to future maintainers.

By itself this won't prevent others from holding on their own `cv::Mat` copy which would share ownership. You can partially prevent that: If ownership could be shared, `clone` the cv::Mat`before putting it into the`std::unique_ptr`. But anyone can later create additional cv::Mat's sharing ownership.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that solution. It is simple and clear for library users.